# 4 cameras recording on one Raspi - a possible workaround for the processing power issue?

Tags: camera

I have been researching an option for a 4 camera recording setup using one raspi. I know it is not possible to do in a simple, straightforward way.

However, I wonder if it would be possible to have the four cameras attached to one RPI using a multicamera module, and then have the RPI switch between the four cameras as fast as possible (so only one camera is active at a time), take a picture with each, and then have a script that stitching the images from each camera together making a low-frame-rate video of sorts for each camera? I need this setup to be able to run for an hour or two at a time - this is to consider the amount of data I will have to store at the end.

This is the hardware I have:

[Raspi 3B](https://www.amazon.ca/Raspberry-Pi-RASPBERRYPI3-MODB-1GB-Model-Motherboard/dp/B01CD5VC92/ref=sr_1_6?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1543260583&sr=1-6&keywords=raspberry%20pi) 
[Cameras](https://www.amazon.ca/Raspberry-camera-Module-Fish-Eye-Infrared/dp/B06XW9DT7X/ref=sr_1_9?ie=UTF8&qid=1543259570&sr=8-9&keywords=raspberry-pi%20camera) 
[adapter](https://www.amazon.ca/Arducam-Camera-Adapter-Compatible-Raspberry/dp/B012UQWOOQ)

This is where I got the idea for the setup:

http://www.arducam.com/multi-camera-adapter-module-raspberry-pi/

So, would this setup be possible, and would I be able to store the data directly on a laptop as whole video files for each camera?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this will use more processing power than just shooting video with an appropriately low framerate.

Comment: [This question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/92658/19949) hints that getting still images of multiple cameras is not a good approach, though we do not know how well the process could be optimized.